# How can I make a scatter plot from a matrix with many y-axis values for each x-axis value?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, matrix

Consider matrix

```
A = 
  {{0, 2.54343, 3.566, 4.2323, 2.3434}, 
   {0.1, 6.432, 4.6465, 5.656, 1.34},  
   {0.2, 0.3423, 1.6342, 3.323, 2.04}};
```

The x-axis values are 0, 0.1, 0.2. There are four y-axis values for each x-axis value.

How do I plot this?

Naive use of

```
ListPlot[A]
```

fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) the list `A` , remove its first list and use the option [`DataRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html):

```
ListPlot[Rest[Transpose@A], DataRange -> {0, .2}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, create new input list with explicit x values for each point:

```
d1 = Thread[{A[[All, 1]], #}]& /@ Rest[Transpose@A];;
ListPlot[d1, Frame -> True, Axes->False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

> same picture

You can also use [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) using `{0, .1, .2}` as the common time stamps:

```
d2 =  TemporalData[Rest/@ A, {A[[All,1]]}];;
ListPlot[d2, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large],  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

> same picture

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP has `A[[All,1]]` as the x-values with `A[[All,{2,3,4,5}]]` as the y-values.

Comment: @JimB, thank you. Fixed the errors now.